# Part entry inside mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have data as follows inside column 'name' from table 'student'

```
jamil-20,raseed-27,akram-32........
```

I need to add this data in table 'detail' as

```
name    |    age      
jamil   |    20    
raseed  |    27    
akram   |    32    
.....   |    ...    
.....   |    ...    
.....   |    ...
```

i have done

```
$values = explode(',', $value_list);

foreach ($values as $value)
{
    $sql="INSERT INTO detail ( name, age)

    VALUES ('$value', '$age')";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

result i get after executing the code is

```
name     |    age 
jamil-20 |    0    
raseed-27|    0    
akram-32 |    0    
.....    |    ...    
.....    |    ...    
.....    |    ...
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with your script is you forgot to parse the values delimited by '-'.

Try this,

```
$values = explode(',', $value_list);

foreach ($values as $value)
{
    list($name, $age) = explode('-', $value);
    $sql="INSERT INTO detail ( name, age) VALUES ('$name', '$age')";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```